Is it good way to instantiate Player Node in root?
So say i have two scenes "Main" and "Second" both should contain player. Now i spawning player in scenes like
func _load_player() -> void:
    # Instantiate player and camera
    var player = player_scene.instantiate()
    var camera = camera_scene.instantiate()
    # Add Nodes to tree
    current_scene.add_child(player)
    current_scene.add_child(camera)
    # Set up player and camera
    camera.player = player
    player.camera_holder = camera

where current_scene is scene to load in root node.
So question is. I can spawn player like these
get_tree().root.add_child(player)
get_tree().root.add_child(camera)

Which pros and cons i could get from that way?
My Pros is that i always know where is my player and camera say i can find it easily get_tree().root.get_node('Player')

I'd recommend creating each level within it's own separate node for easy loading and self containment and instance your player in each separately. Things such as menus, splash screens, level manager, etc are more Ideal as children of root node. As for "finding them easily" create a Global autoload to to keep track of your player, camera, etc
